# Como Arreglar el problema encontrado el modulo Angular + PHP

Tags: angular

hola les presento mi inconveniente y es que estoy realizando un proyecto y al momento de colocar las rutas para comunicarme con el servicio, me dice que no la encuentra, si me pueden ayudar por favor, dejo las imágenes
[image: Este es el servicio]

[image: Y este el componente]

Comment: siempre acostúmbrese a dejar el código y no imágenes. Así es mas fácil intentar darte ayuda